# Service Bus message broker services wouldn't start

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, workflow-manager

I need assistance with my Sharepoint 2016 (on prem) installation.  I have 2 servers in my farm, an App server and a DB server. The Service Bus message broker server went into 'starting' and remains there.  I've tried several solutions:
I stopped it and restarted after restarting Fabric host, workflow manager and service bus gateway services.
I've left the farm and rejoined again, but it gets stuck where it needs to start the service bus message broker.  So I uninstalled Workflow manager completely and restarted from scratch with new port numbers (in case it was used by another process) But still the service bus message broker will not start.  What else can I try - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether the Service Bus ports are used with other web applications or blocked by firewall mentioned at following article:

https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/service-bus-message-broker-stuck-on-starting/

Comment: Thank you, I did the check on the ports. But the IT confirmed they installed a cyber security software that check for vulnerable ports and automatic block them. The software blocked the service bus ports. They changed the setting and the Service Bus started without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into an issue where the Service Bus Message broker wouldn't start, as well, during the initial farm configuration.

You can try adding the service account to the Administrators group on the system as a troubleshooting measure to see if it is a permissions issue.  For my case, it seems that it may have been a permissions issue.

Later, however, when trying to add another server to the farm, the message broker once again got stuck.  This time I was seeing repeated messages in the Event Viewer -> Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft-ServiceBus -> Operational log:

Windows Fabric service registration failed.  Retries remaing: 3. Exception System.Fabric.FabricException: Service Type is already registered.

This error continued until the Add-SBHost would return as failed due to time out of starting services. Running Get-SBFarmStatus would show that the ServiceBus Message Broker was in a state of StartPending.

I initially used the Workflow Manager Configuration wizard, but exported the PowerShell commands for joining a host to the farm and used PowerShell ISE to run the commands one after the other.

Since it was timing out trying to start the services, I finally tried launching the Add-SBHost command and then used task manager to End Task on the Microsoft.Servicebus.MessageBroker.exe process.   This took the service out of StartPending.  Then, I simply started the Service Bus Message Broker from services.msc.   It started up immediately when I did that.  Then, the Add-SBHost ran through successfully.

I ran through the rest of the join farm commands in the PowerShell script after that.

This blog was helpful, and I tried many of the steps listed in this blog as I was troubleshooting: https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/service-bus-message-broker-stuck-on-starting/